# Difficulties in understanding a statistics question

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Consider the following question:-
[image]

I have recently learned statistics theory and am a bit confused by this question. My doubts are:-

1. Does "uniformly distributed" here mean that each of X1, X2, X3... Xn have continuous uniform distribution?
2. If the answer to 1 is yes, then wouldn't X1, X2, X3...Xn be identical since each would have probability density=1 at all points on [0,1]
3. If the answer to 1 is no, then how are they distributed?
4. I don't understand how Y can be the largest of X1, X2,X3...Xn because X1,X2,X3...Xn are random variables and thus can take different values. So how can you define the "largest" random variable?

A complete solution to the problem in minute detail will be appreciated.

Also, is the language of the question unclear or is it just my inexperience? If it's my inexperience, please can you suggest what I can do(besides solving problems) to gain a better theoretical understanding of statistics and its terminology(in a short time).

Comment: 1. yes. 2. $X_i$ are identical, yes.

Comment: 4. Let consider similar discrete case. Let we have two players rolling a die. Let $X_1$ random variable corresponding to first player result, $X_2$ – the same for other player. Both $X_1$ and $X_2$ have uniform distribution. Consider largest result of two players. It is random variable, having some distribution.

Comment: Please refrain from asking multiple questions at a time. Consider making separate posts next time.

Comment: What does the hint says about $P(Y<\lambda)$? Think about the independence of the $X_j$.